# c++20 and c++11 standards both specified in tasks.json, still won't work?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, visual-studio-code, c++20

I'm learning C++ using Visual Studio Code. I'm starting to pull my hair out trying to figure why the compiler won't recognize C++11 standards. The code + .json file + error are as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector <int> vector_numbers;

    for (int i : vector_numbers) {
        vector_numbers[1] = i + 1;
    }

    for (int i : vector_numbers) {
        cout << "The vector element at index [" << i << "] is " << vector_numbers.at(i) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The contents of "args" parameter in tasks.json is

```
            "args": [
                "-std=c++11",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-std=c++20",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ]
```

and error is:

```
<REDACTED> % cd "<REDACTED PATH>" && g++ Vectors.cpp -o Vectors && "<REDACTED PATH>"Vectors
Vectors.cpp:9:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (int i : vector_numbers) {
               ^
Vectors.cpp:13:16: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for (int i : vector_numbers) {
               ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: From the console output, none of the `args` in your `tasks.json` are actually making their way to the compiler invocation. Double-check that you're actually using that json file at all?

Comment: Also, gcc enables C++14 by default since version 6.1, so your compiler must be old. You may consider upgrading it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen
CLI command `g++ -v` returns:
'Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: <REDACTED>'

Comment: Later flags override prior ones, but there is no reason to use `-std=c++11` when you are using `-std=c++20`. Only the latter is sufficient. But as mentioned above, none of the flags are actually being used by the shown compilation, so you must have put them in the wrong place (or not saved the file or something similar). Also, you are using Clang, not GCC. You are probably on an Apple device, where `g++` is aliased to `clang++`.

Comment: clang 13 should eat that code and smile, so there's got to be a `-std=c++98` lurking somewhere off camera. grep around for it.

Comment: Passing three different standards seems like a bad idea. Pick one and put it in the right place and you should be good to go.

Comment: @user4581301 If I remember correctly Apple's clang defaults to c++98.

Comment: [Looks like your memory serves you well](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-703.0.29/src/tools/clang/www/cxx_status.html). Colour me a bright shade of surprised. Apple is weird, but why the <expletive deleted> would they do that?

Comment: Yeah, well, that means your compiler is pretty okay. Consider my previous comment non-existent.

Comment: my understanding is either running the code or using the hotkey 'command + shift + n' runs the code, but when reviewing the terminal commands it's not using tasks.json. From what I can tell it _should_ be located in the .vscode directory. I'm completely lost.

Answer (score 0):

OK, issue resolved and posting solution for posterity.

The issue was with coderunner extension not using -std=c++20 in the CLI argument. For coderunner's settings.json file should be:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {

        "javascript": "node",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ **-std=c++20** $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "php": "php",
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        "perl6": "perl6",
        "ruby": "ruby",
        "go": "go run",
        "lua": "lua",
        "groovy": "groovy",
        "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
        "bat": "cmd /c",
        "shellscript": "bash",
        "fsharp": "fsi",
        "csharp": "scriptcs",
        "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
        "typescript": "ts-node",
        "coffeescript": "coffee",
        "scala": "scala",
        "swift": "swift",
        "julia": "julia",
        "crystal": "crystal",
        "ocaml": "ocaml",
        "r": "Rscript",
        "applescript": "osascript",
        "clojure": "lein exec",
        "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "racket": "racket",
        "scheme": "csi -script",
        "ahk": "autohotkey",
        "autoit": "autoit3",
        "dart": "dart",
        "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "haskell": "runhaskell",
        "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
        "lisp": "sbcl --script",
        "kit": "kitc --run",
        "v": "v run",
        "sass": "sass --style expanded",
        "scss": "scss --style expanded",
        "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
        "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
        "sml": "cd $dir && sml $fileName"
    }
```

Key config param is -std=c++20 for "cpp".